# How to validate if the input text (in html) is a valid Phone Number when user hits the 11th number?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

I have an input.

```
<input id="phoneNumber"/>
```

How can I validate if the inserted value from user is a valid phone number or not using jQuery ?

Thanks.

Comment: Using some code and by providing some code to look into it of how far you tried and facing problem

Comment: You can do that directly inside of your input tag, something like this.

```
<input name="phoneNum" id="phoneNum" maxlength="11" type="tel">
Number of chars: <span id="phoneNumCounter">5</span>
```

Then just use some UI validation with JS.

 Following this logic, if all of the inputs have their requirements, then the button is clickable, else it's not. 
Best of luck

Comment: @TomasMota it is useful when you have a submit button, but not in my case

Comment: Then you don't need that logic. Just add that to your input tag and it should do what wanted, right? Or wasn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: @TomasMota not it is not what I'm looking for, I want something that validates at the time user is inserting the numbers

Comment: You can use keypress event and when input length reaches 11 than show warning

Comment: I believe that you can do that with this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/form-validation-using-html-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `oninput` to check if input has some values entered or not.

When 10th value is entered you can use a `alert` but this will not be enough because after `alert`, user can still enter more values. So use `maxlength="10"` to allow only 10 numbers.

Also if you don't want to allow `text` but numbers only than you can use `.replace(/[^\d]/, '')` to replace any non-number . And show that it is not a number.

```js
function validPhone(phoneNum)
//  check for valid phone numbers in the format 999-999-9999
{
  if (phoneNum.value.match(/[^\d]/)) {
    phoneNum.value = phoneNum.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '')
    document.querySelector("#demo1").innerHTML = "Sorry numbers only";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#demo1").innerHTML = "";
  }
  var strPhone = phoneNum.value;
  var rePhone = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/;

  if (strPhone.length >= 10) {
    phoneNum.select();
    document.querySelector("#demo1").innerHTML ="No more numbers plz, only 10 digits allowed in Phone number.";
  }
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = strPhone.length;
};
```

```css
#demo1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" oninput="validPhone(this)" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Phone number" maxlength="10" id="phoneNumberForForgotPassword" data-val-required="نام کاربری را وارد نمائید.">

<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```